# PHP post variables in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this piece of SQL that should retrieve a room, based on its roomID:

```
$sql="SELECT room FROM Rooms WHERE roomID = $_POST[roomID]";
```

(roomID is a variable)

Why is this not working?

EDIT: The code works if I put a number instead of $_POST[roomID] (or $_POST['roomID'])

EDIT2: This is my code:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $date = $row['date'];
            $period = $row['period'];
            $roomID = $row['roomID'];
            $teacherinitials = $row['teacherinitials'];

            $sql2="SELECT room FROM Rooms WHERE roomID = $_POST[roomID]";

            $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

            while ($row2 = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $room = $row2['room'];
                    $description = $row2['description'];
            }
```

I get the roomID from the user input, then I'm trying to use that to look up the room that the roomID corresponds to in another table.

Comment: you need `$_POST['roomID']`, be careful of SQL Injections.

Comment: You need to give a lot more information. What error are you getting?

Comment: Tin Tran, this doesn't seem to work. Nothing shows up at all, not even my navigation bar, separate from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql="SELECT room FROM Rooms WHERE roomID = $_POST[roomID]";  // not working
```

Possible reasons:

1. `$_POST['roomID']` not set
2. `roomID` not quoted in your statement - `$_POST['roomID']`
3. Variable not quoted in your query:

   $roomID = $_POST['roomID'];

   $sql="SELECT room FROM Rooms WHERE roomID = '$roomID'";
4. Failure to execute query - this happens a lot.
5. Unknow field used in query
6. Any of many other reasons

Do some debugging. Look in your server error log.

...and remember to escape your user input before you send it to your database.

Comment: Thank you!! Number 3 solved it!! I was supposed to write '$roomID', not $_POST['roomID']

Comment: This **needs** to use [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add values. Using string interpolation is completely wrong. Adding quotes to solve the problem turns non-functional code into a functional SQL injection bug.

Comment: @tadman Actually, no binding is required since this is not using prepared statements. There is a reminder to escape user data, but in this case if you read the OP comments and look at his posted code you'll see that user data is not involved here. This is an attempt to help someone resolve a problem. Your arbitrary, inaccurate and irrelevant comment isn't helpful.

Comment: `$_POST` is **always** user data and if it's directly in the query you have a problem. Period. No exceptions. Your flagrant dismissal of this is worrying to an extreme. Placeholders are the safest way to achieve proper escaping, and that they're not being used here is a problem. Your "fix" here turns non-functional code into a gigantic liability.

Comment: @tadman It seems that you are unable to understand the nature of the original problem. The use of `$_POST` was itself the mistake: `$_POST` should not have appeared here at all. The arbitrary way you invoke prepared statements shows no understanding of the nature of them and ignores the many cases where they offer no benefit, or simply cannot be used. Your attempt to fix the world as you see it is simply muddying the waters, and unhelpful comments such as yours serve only to reduce the value of this site.

Comment: Maybe `$_POST` was a mistake, but it's repeated several times in your answer, each time with zero escaping. Binding data against placeholders *ensures* it's escaped properly. Using string concatenation is extremely risky. Why does the PHP community insist on fighting against placeholders? This attitude is completely unlike every other group that uses MySQL where placeholders are the de-facto way of doing this. Why are you protesting so much about what's the bare minimum one needs to do when writing SQL code?

Comment: @tadman 'Bare minimum'? Hardly. The unthinking way that prepared statements are touted here as being the 'only way' is promoting a breed of programmers that have no understanding of what they're doing, and produce some of the worst implementations of database code imaginable. My objection stems from the arbitrary and unconsidered nature of such comments. If you're so convinced of the value of your 'one-size-fits-all' approach you're welcome to submit your own answer, rather than picking unnecessary holes in an answer that has clearly identified the original problem.

Comment: Prepared statements aren't the only way, but if you're avoiding their use you better have a very good reason. 99% of the time they're the most reliable way to ensure proper escaping. 1% they're difficult to implement correctly because PDO and `mysqli` don't implement them very well. Your assertion that it produces "some of the worst implementations" is completely unfounded. There are literally *thousands* of examples here of people not using prepared statements and exposing themselves to serious trouble. The number of those that use them correctly and have the same problem is almost zero.